# Selenium - Difference between text_to_be_present_in_element and text_to_be_present_in_element_value

Tags: python, selenium, expected-condition

Can you illustrate the difference between `text_to_be_present_in_element` and 
`text_to_be_present_in_element_value` with an example, preferably in python ?

The following link seems to explain how text_to_be_present_in_element works but it's still unclear to me.

http://www.seleniumframework.com/python-basic/waits-and-synchronization/

Comment: Okay so there is an explanation here but it doesn't make things any clearer.https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`text_to_be_present_in_element` is text value, to get the value with selenium `element.text` or Javascript `element.textContent` or `element.innerTEXT`

```
<p>this is text</p>
```

`text_to_be_present_in_element_value` is `value` attribute for element, to get the value with selenium `element.get_attribute('value')` and with JS `element.getAttribute('value')`

```
<input type="text" value="text value">
<input type="button" value="button text value">
```

Comment: I'm waiting to see if a button element on my page whose text is "SAVE" appears on the page. The following syntax doesn't work as expected. 
save_button = WebDriverWait(chrome_browser, 60).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element(chrome_browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("button"),"SAVE"))
print("SAVE BUTTON TEXT IS {}".format(save_button.text))

Comment: try using `presence_of_element_located` or create new question with relevant html or URL

Comment: `save_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[text()="SAVE"]')))` for text and for value replace `text()` with `@value`